# How to see the real SQL query in Python cursor.execute using cx_Oracle

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I use the following code in Python (with CX_ORACLE for a oracle base)

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(connectString)
cur = con.cursor()
sandy_pet_statement = 'select name, owner, type from cx_pets 
where owner = :owner and  anyparam= :any_param'
args = {':owner': sandy_id ,':any_param' = 'anyname'}
cur.execute(sandy_pet_statement,args )
res = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: Can you fix your code formatting? You can do so by editing your question, highlighting your code and pressing the `{}` button (or CTRL+K)

Comment: What do you mean *real SQL query*?

Answer (score 0):

One solution on the app side (as opposed the DB tracing), is subclassing, see https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/Subclassing.py

```
class Cursor(cx_Oracle.Cursor):

    def execute(self, statement, args):
        print("EXECUTE", statement)
        print("ARGS:")
        for argIndex, arg in enumerate(args):
            print("   ", argIndex + 1, "=>", repr(arg))
        return super(Cursor, self).execute(statement, args)
```